# How much memory usage is too much for an XNA game?

Tags: c#, memory, xna

I'm making a game in XNA 4.0 and C#. Once I've completed the overall gameplay, I'm going to work on optimising the code so that it won't use too much memory. But that got me thinking: How much memory usage is too much? The game isn't finished yet, but I wanted to check its memory usage in its current state using Task Manager. According to Task Manager, the memory usage mostly stays at a steady 85 MB, but it can also increase to 95-100 MB at certain points (such as when playing a level with multiple objects to update and textures to draw). I don't think that the memory usage has ever been above 101 MB. For a game made in XNA and C#, is 100 MB or even 85 MB considered to be too much? If it is, what's the target amount that I should try to decrease it to?

Also, the game is intended to be played on Windows PCs, rather than something like Android in case that's helpful. :)

Comment: Considering PCs usually have memory starting from 4GB, 100MB isn't much. It all depends on what you're doing. If it's a "guess a number", it might be a lot. If it's a AAA FPS game, 100MB is very little. If you don't have a problem, don't optimize for nothing.

Comment: Thanks. It's a 2D platforming game. It's going to feature about 60 levels, each containing multiple enemies and items. The levels are all fairly small (only lasting about 10 seconds each) and I have 40 of them done so far.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about memory usage too much in a simple 2D game unless you plan on people with crappy machines using it. Just make sure there are no memory leaks or unnecessarily large things stored in memory and you'll be fine.

Comment: Cheers. Hopefully everything will turn out fine. :)